# How to store scheduled cron reference in database to stop that cron in future in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, cron

I am using [cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron) to schedule push notifications. I am collecting the push notification data and the scheduled time from the user to send the push notification at a scheduled time.

Here is how I am creating a cron job to schedule push notification :

```js
const CronJob = require("cron").CronJob;
...
...
const schedulePushNotification = async (req, res) => {
  const job = new CronJob(
    new Date(req.body.scheduledTime),
    async () => {
      // my code to send push notification
      // code to store push notification data
      // Here I write a code to store push notification data to 
      // show on the dashboard like a list of notification
    },
    null,
    true,
    "America/Los_Angeles"
  );
  
  job.start();
  return res.status(200).json({
    success: true,
    message: "Notification has been scheduled successfully !",
    data: null,
  });
};
```

Now, The requirement is that If users want to cancel the scheduled push notification, they can do by clicking on cancel.

So, How I can destroy the running cron?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by adding a if statement inside the function

you can check if user activated notification, but first you have to store whether user activated the notification or not in database then send the notification

```
const CronJob = require("cron").CronJob;
...
...
const schedulePushNotification = async (req, res) => {
  const job = new CronJob(
    new Date(req.body.scheduledTime),
    async () => {



      let userNotificationDetails = getUserNotificationDetails();
      if(userNotificationDetails.isSendNotification){
          job.start();
      } else {
          // don't send notification
      }



      // my code to send push notification
      // code to store push notification data
      // Here I write a code to store push notification data to 
      // show on the dashboard like a list of notification
    },
    null,
    true,
    "America/Los_Angeles"
  );
  
  
  return res.status(200).json({
    success: true,
    message: "Notification has been scheduled successfully !",
    data: null,
  });
};
```

.

**Edit (alternative solution: checking if isNotification before starting cron):**

```
const CronJob = require("cron").CronJob;
...
...
const schedulePushNotification = async (req, res) => {
  const job = new CronJob(
    new Date(req.body.scheduledTime),
    async () => {
      // my code to send push notification
      // code to store push notification data
      // Here I write a code to store push notification data to 
      // show on the dashboard like a list of notification
    },
    null,
    true,
    "America/Los_Angeles"
  );



  let userNotificationDetails = getUserNotificationDetails();
  if(userNotificationDetails.isSendNotification){
      job.start();
  } else {
      // don't send notification
  }
  



  return res.status(200).json({
    success: true,
    message: "Notification has been scheduled successfully !",
    data: null,
  });
};
```

Comment: It's good but it will not stop cron job. It just don't send notification. I want to completely destroy the cron job when user cancel the notification. Whether in your answer cron job don't destroy.

Comment: It that even posible or not ? Please tell me If is possible or not otherwise your answer is perfect solution

Comment: you can alternatively add the if else when executing the `job.start()` and see what happens. I have edited the answer

Comment: It only work initially. When I stop notification It will not destroy the cron job.

Comment: Yes it is a problem. I use `node-cron` which has `destroy()` method where you can destroy a cron job, But I don't know much about `cron` and how to destroy it!!

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by adding an if statement inside the function

you can check if user activated notification, but first, you have to store whether the user activated the notification or not in the database then send the notification

Comment: That does not stop actual running cron. It's just not run a function when the cron schedule complete. I want to destroy the actual cron that have created.